# How can i create a PDF form, than fill it with user generated data in Java, with iText?

Tags: java, forms, pdf, itext, edit

Let's say if i have this PDF form. How can i fill it with user generated data, in Java?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance:

```
 PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
 form.getField("test").setValue(value);
```

You can find a lot of examples there: 
https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/filling-out-forms